# ¿Cómo incrustar incluir archivo dentro de los datos que almacena una variable?

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente variable `$detalle` que obtiene datos desde la base de datos, está variable almacena el detalle o la descripción completa del artículo, en ella existen texto comunes, como también código `HTML` dado a qué los datos enviados a dicha variable es por medio de un editor similar a este, que reemplaza textarea con un editor.

Esa variable tiene contenido texto, código HTML, etc separados por párrafo es decir `<p></p>` entonces mediante PHP como puedo incluir / incrustar un archivo PHP o código PHP por decir incluir `data1.php` en el párrafo 3, así incluir otros en el párrafo 6 y, así sucesivamente cuando lo desee, siempre en cuando existan esos párrafos por decir si tengo un artículo de dos párrafos entonces no se va incluir o incrustar nada porque no cumple la condición.

Es importante que sea en `PHP` dado a qué en `Javascript` y `jQuery` no funciona cuando tienen desactivado la depuración de JAVASCRIPT en el navegador ocasionandome una mala imagen de diseño.

He probado solo `strrpos()` pero para buscar algún dato en específico, no tengo más código que mostrar dado a qué todo parece ser sencillo pero nunca he forzado incluir datos en una variable.

Ejemplo:

```
include 'file1.php';
include 'file2.php';

//Deben incluirse o incrustarse en la variable $detalle el primer archivo en el tercer párrafo y el segundo archivo en el séptimo párrafo.

echo $detalle;
```

Comment: Hola! Siempre será muchísimo más fácil saber qué intentas hacer (y darte una buena respuesta) si tu pregunta tiene un ejemplo mínimo verificable. Datos de prueba, salida esperada, salida actual de ese código de ejemplo, etc.

Comment: @Alfabravo Hola, agregue un ejemplo al final de la pregunta, no puedo proporcionar más información por qué no veo como poder insertar esos archivos en una variable :/